# Pagination with search in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am making log table which consist of all the logs in the project, Using the pagination of CI i have created pagination data. Now the problem is i have to filter the logs according to the different log type and pagination also, I have tried a lot but still not able to figure it out how to generate paginated links for search. I am pasting the controller code 
Thank You.

```
{

    if($this->input->post('show'))
        $logtype_filter = $this->input->post('log_type');
    else
        $logtype_filter ='';

    // load pagination class
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url().'admin/logs/';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('netsynclogtable');
    $config['per_page'] = '20';
    $config['first_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['last_link'] = FALSE;
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next">';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="previous">';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    //load the model and get results
    $this->load->model('Logger_model');
    $data['logs'] = $this->Logger_model->get_logs($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3),$logtype_filter);
    $data['logtypes'] = $this->Logger_model->get_log_types();
    $data['_view'] = 'admin/logs';
    // load the view

    $this->load->view('layouts/admin',$data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a look at [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/). It supports almost everything you would need to do with a table. There's also a [Codeigniter library](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160896/) for that  but I haven't tested it

Comment: I do not want to use any jquery plugins, Any ways thanks for the reply but still is there any way to do it in CI without using any Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your log type in base_url like this:

```
  $config['base_url'] =
  base_url().'admin/logs?log_type='.$this->input->get('log_type', TRUE)';
```

I have used GET request here as on clicking the NEXT link in pager HTTP method called is GET not POST. As post will only work whne you submit the serach form. So once search form is submitted and result is shown with paging,now on click of the pagging link GET request is genrated as serach form is not submitted.

Hope this helps.